# Creating a date range in Pandas/Python with just the year

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataframe, df. This dataframe includes a column called "Accession Year." I need to create a date range. I've tried running this code, but it didn't work

```
index = df.AccessionYear.date_range(start = '1877',end='2020')
```

Unfortunately, this column does not have any months or days, only the year. The error message that I am getting is " AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date_range'". Would anyone happen to know any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

`date_range` is a method coming from `pandas` class, you should do:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range(start = '1877',end='2020')
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully, and think about what you coded.

`Accession_Year` is a column of strings (inferring from your attempt to call the method).  Why do you think a column of strings has a method `date_range`?

If you need an absolute date range, as indicated in your post, why did you insert `Accession_Year` into the call?  You use simply

```
pd.date_range(start='1877', end='2020')
```

If the column *does* affect the call, you need to explain how, such as

```
pd.date_range(start=df.Accession_Year.min(), end='2020')
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed I would have to call the column so that python would know which column I needed the date range for